# casting vector<int> to vector<long> when they are the same size?

Tags: c++, casting, reference

I have a function taking a reference to a vector of longs

```
Void blarf(std::vector<long>&);
```

This is given and shouldn't be modified.   Deep into xyz.cpp is an attempt to feed `blarf()` a `vector` of `int`s:

```
std::vector<int>  gooddata;
. . . 
blarf(gooddata);
```

In my case and all cases for this software, `int` and `long` are the same size.  Of course I can't change the definition of `gooddata` either.

What kind of typecast is appropriate here?  I tried `dynamic_cast` but that's only for polymorphic class conversion.  `static_cast` no worky either.  I'm no genius at c++ type casts.

Comment: Yee, this is ugly formatting.  Will fix it when i get home.

Comment: You can use `reinterpret_cast` if you're willing to risk undefined behavior.

Comment: As an aside, consider templates if your code can afford it: `template <typename T> void blarf(std::vector<T> &);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't. `int` and `long` will stay different types, this would break strict aliasing rules.

You can create a `vector<long>` from your `vector<int>` very easily:

```
std::vector<int> vec{5, 3, 7, 9};
std::vector<long> veclong(begin(vec), end(vec));
```

This will copy `vec` into `veclong`, with the constructor of `vector` that takes two iterators.

If you want to do it the bad way (i.e. that exhibits undefined behavior), then feel free to use:

```
*reinterpret_cast<std::vector<long>*>(&vec)
```

Comment: or simply
reinterpet_cast<std::vector<long>&> (vec)

Comment: @Catriel typo reinterpret_cast<std::vector<long>&> (vec)