# optimization-friendy vector casting/transformation

Tags: c++, c++17, compiler-optimization

I don't beleive there exists a good answer for this question. Most of the answers suggest [range-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40389933/9363996) or `std::transform`. And sometimes it is advised to *"rely on a SmartCompiler™ to understand what you want and to perform the necessary optimizations"*.

However, I don't beleive there's a way to do with `vector` the same that is perfectly allowed for a standard-layout pod structure:

```
struct S1 { int a; } s1;
int* p1 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&s1); // value of p1 is "pointer to s1.a" because
                                       // s1.a and s1 are pointer-interconvertible
```

I assume that also stands for casting dynamic arrays `auto s1 = new S1[n];`.
There are a lot of similar questions where similar casts are required (cast to base type pointer of the same size and layout maybe).

I do beleive that such **type conversions** should be possible in a wann-be-low-level language like C++. However, I don't see how it can be done using the Standard Library and not get an unnecessary reallocations and copying.

Here is a naive code that results in a very bloated assembly code:
https://godbolt.org/z/34Grvb9Gj

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

struct Int
{
    int value;
};

static std::vector<Int> init(size_t size){
    std::vector<Int> res;
    res.reserve(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        res.push_back(Int{int(i)});

    return res;
}

int stdTransform(size_t size){

    // const size_t size = 815;
    auto wrapped = init(size);

    std::vector<int> out;
    out.reserve(size);

    std::transform(std::move_iterator(wrapped.begin()), std::move_iterator(wrapped.end()),
        std::back_inserter(out), 
        [](Int&& v) {
            const int r = v.value;
            v.value = {};
            return r;
        });
    
    return std::accumulate(out.cbegin(), out.cend(), 0);
}
```

I can see 2 call to `operator new` there. Generally I don't expect that a simple type conversion (which in this case should result in `zero` instructions) would generate that amount of instructions with `-O3`.

More over, if I remove the input argument `size` (`void stdTransform()`) and hardcode initialization to `const size_t size = 815;` there's still a lot of instructions.
With the `size` known at compile time I expect that **everything should be evaluated at compile time**, like it would be with `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.

Taking this context into consideration, the questions are simple:

1. Is there a way to cast `std::vector` without reallocations?
2. Why the compiler can't optimize away the transformation, when there's clearly no side effects for the pod type's construction/destruction? (also `bad_alloc` here doesn't ,ake any sense, because we don't have any intention for reallocations).

---

I have found the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34590885/9363996) that explains why `vector`'s allocation is not optimized out, as apposed to plain calls of `new[]` and `delete[]`.
I am not sure though whether something like (below) would help the compiler to optimize out reallocation and copy.

```
// Assumming `To` and `From` have the same size, layout, members and member types.
template <typename To, typename From>
std::unique_ptr<To[]> cast_array(std::unique_ptr<From[]> from)
{
// the non-UB'est code possible here
}
```

From the perspective of a low-level programmer, `From` and `To` arrays are guaranteed to be the same data. The question is in how to help the compiler realize that and to not perform meta-programming logic at runtime.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255288/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-kolesnik-optimization-friendy-vector-casting-tr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to cast std::vector without reallocations?

If you want to cast and work on the data while keeping the original vector alive, one standard way is to use a span:

```cpp
int cast_using_span(size_t size) {
    auto wrapped = init(size);
    std::span<int> out = std::span<int>(reinterpret_cast<int*>(wrapped.data()), wrapped.size());
    return std::accumulate(out.begin(), out.end(), 0);
}
```

`span<T>` is compatible in many ways to a `const vector<T>&`, but you might have to adapt your downstream code to work with it.

Note that such cast will only work if there's no padding in the struct, i.e. `sizeof(Int) == sizeof(int)`, which is usually true for an `int`, but for example not true for a `bool` by default.

Also beware of "strict aliasing rule optimizations" on GCC that in some cases might lead to changes on the original vector after span creation not be reflected in the span as [shown here by
Vincent Saulue-Laborde](https://godbolt.org/z/s11Yq8bMT).

With that said, there's an UB way that might work in some contexts:

```cpp
int cast_using_UB(size_t size) {
    auto wrapped = init(size);
    std::vector<int>* out = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(&wrapped);
    return std::accumulate(out->cbegin(), out->cend(), 0);
}
```

This assumes that there's no specialization for `vector<int>` and that both `vector<Int>` and `vector<int>` have identical memory layout.

If you want to cast and move ownership of the underlying buffer to the new vector instance, this is not possible with stdlib unforunately. Part of the reason it is not implemented is how custom allocators complicate things. I think it is a solvable problem and it could be a useful addition to the standard to support this use case.

See also a related question for std::string: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/vcjk35/stdstring_to_byte_buffer_without_copy/

> Why the compiler can't optimize away the transformation, when there's clearly no side effects for the pod type's construction/destruction?

Because the code operates on 2 separate vector instances that have 2 separate data buffers. `std::move_iterator` has no effect, because `struct Int` is a trivial value type. Even if it wasn't, you can't move the `wrapped.data()` buffer this way. The only supported way to move it (in the current stdlib) is to another instance of the same `vector<T>` type as the source vector, no casting allowed.

> With the size known at compile time I expect that everything should be evaluated at compile time

This is a bit too optimistic :)
In the particular way you write `res.reserve(815)` there's no magic that would do that. It simply calls the default allocator.

In theory if we create a vector with `std::vector<Int> res{815};` we could imagine that an stdlib of some future C++35 will be smarter, constexpr everything, and back this by `std::array<Int, 55>` internally.

The current way to achieve such behaviour (make a statically allocated std::vector) is to use a custom allocator. For example see this: [Hinnant's short_alloc and alignment guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722907/hinnants-short-alloc-and-alignment-guarantees)

TLDR; C++ std::vector and std::string don't allow "casting" without a copy if you can't keep the original vector around, otherwise it is possible using non-owning span/views/pointers. A concrete solution to this problem be to either have a custom type instead of std::vector, or make all downstream code generic to accept any collection like std::vector, std::span, range etc.

Comment: Your first std::span solution is also UB. There is no way to cast an array of a type to another type, it might still work if the memory layout is the same, but it is UB.

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned that the alignment layout must match, that is have no padding after int. The struct layout is fairly well-defined in the docs, in that sense it is a "defined behaviour" DB :)

Comment: In regards to things in the example like `reserve` - that was done to express the intent in hope that the compiler would understand what is needed. And the question is basically about _"how to explain to the compiler that casting `A` to `B` is pure meta and the data is guaranteed to be of the same layout and padding"_. Like when the commonly accepted practice is to use `std::copy` an array vs type punning  via `reinterpret_cast`: _"SmartCompiler™ will understand and remove the copy"_. In general C++ is sold like a Zero Cost Abstraction language. More like **Zero Abstraction Cost**

Comment: Another one (my favorite): "You pay only for what you use." ... But you HAVE to use the copy because otherwise it's UB. Nice job

Comment: @battlmonstr My point is that this is UB even if the layout must be the same according to the standard. The standard says that pointer arithmetic is undefined if the type of the pointer is different from the type of the array, it doesn't matter if the layout is the same or not; and you need pointer aritmetic to actually iterate over the span.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I understand your question, and tried to provide a reasonable approach with what C++ provides. TLDR; C++ std::vector and std::string don't allow "casting" without a copy if you can't keep the original vector around, otherwise it is possible using non-owning span/views/pointers. A concrete solution to this could be to either have a custom type instead of std::vector, or make all downstream code generic to accept any collection like std::vector, std::span, range etc.

Comment: @ThePirate42 where can I learn more about the behaviour you're describing regarding pointer arithmetic and span, that even when 2 types align, the span won't work? Is it only for structs or primitive types too?

Comment: @battlmonstr "it is not possible with vector or string and there's no sane workaraounds" is a valid answer for the question. Which leads to the conclusion a lot of people have come to: "don't use the Standard Library"

Comment: @battlmonstr https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#note-1 also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic In the "Additive operators" section, it's said that *In any case, if the pointed-to type is different from the array element type, disregarding cv-qualifications, at every level if the elements are themselves pointers, the behavior of pointer arithmetic is undefined*, no exceptions. Different type is automatically UB, even if the layout is the same. I think on most compilers it works anyway, but this could change in the future.

Comment: @battlmonstr I'll also add that in your precise situation (building a `std::span<int>` from `std::vector<Int>`), you have some implicit protection from "strict aliasing rule optimizations" because the compiler has to assume `span[i]` could be a valid alias of `vector[j].value` (both are int). If it were `span<Int2>` with `struct Int2 { int value; }` (same layout as `Int`), you can easily observe [extremely inconsistent/counterintuitive results](https://godbolt.org/z/s11Yq8bMT) in practice.

Comment: @battlmonstr Looking at your edit, I find it a bit misleading. This isn't a GCC exclusive problem. In my snippet, the program has undefined behaviour, because it doesn't respect the strict aliasing rule. Therefore, the C++ standard grants all compilers the right to emit nonsensical assembly from this code. GCC unluckily emitted nonsense that didn't behave as we would like, while clang luckily generated nonsense behaving as intended (clang also uses strict aliasing for optimizations). My point: your `vector<T>` to `span<U>` conversion must not be used if it violates strict aliasing.

Comment: @VincentSaulue-Laborde I'm trying to stay pragmatic here as I see a practical value in such conversions even though some of them are not "by the book". I wish GCC had a way to disable this optimization for parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to C++20, you can use [std::ranges::transform_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view):

```
int int_transform_view_accumulate(){

    auto wrapped = init();

    auto out = wrapped | std::views::transform([](Int& i) -> int& {return reinterpret_cast<int&>(i);});

    return std::accumulate(out.begin(), out.end(), 0);

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dcc83ce5j
new is never called (I didn't define init to isolate the example, of course there would be a call to new inside it).

By casting each element separately, this avoids UB. If you are limited to C++17, you can use the ranges-v3 library.

Comment: This seem nice, but the question is not about the example. The example is about the question (maybe I need to make the intent more clear). Just assume that I need a function that takes the `vector<A>` (with the ownership) and returns the exact same data but in `vector<B>`. `A` and `B` have the exact same layout and padding. Their existense is based purelly on meta template stuff. It's clear I don't have to pay for the cast.  So, should I give up on `std::vector` completelly then?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik You can't cast a pointer to an array of a certain element type to a pointer to an array of any other element type, it will always be undefined behavior (even if T1 and T2 have the same layout). This is true for any kind of contiguous range, like `T a[3]`, `new T[3]`, `std::vector` or `std::array`. You either have to do it anyway and hope UB doesn't bite you, rely on optimizations or cast every element separately, either manually or like in my answer. I guess this could be changed in a future standard, but as of now this is how it is.

Comment: I feel terrible that I fail to express the intent. I am aware that there are things which are deemed UB because of some decisions of the C++ commitee. The question is not about "using `reinterpret_cast` that results in UB". The question is about "what means does the language provide instead". The means to do as advertized: provide a zero cost high level abstraction. The answer which says _"it's not possible with `std::vector` because heap allocations are not allowed to be optimized"_ is also a valid answer.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik The zero cost means that the language provides instead are, for example, what I wrote in my answer. The problem is not that what you want is UB with `reinterpret_cast`, it's explicitly UB by itself, you can't treat any kind of array as a whole as if it was of another type, no matter if the two types are "in practice" the same. By consequence, a std::vector<A> can't give the ownership of it's heap allocated array to std::vector<B>, because this operation would require to cast that array from A to B, which is UB no matter how you do it, and the stdlib can't support UB behavior.

Comment: _"you can't treat any kind of array as a whole as if it was of another type"_ so many thousands of embedded developers would argue with you _"but I need to"_. I can't see how the necessity of expressing such low level things is not obvious. The fact is that language in this case chops of the legs but doesn't provide even a wheelchair

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Regarding optimizations, heap optimizations *are* allowed to be optimized, according to the as-if rule. In this case I think the compiler simply isn't smart enough, optimizations aren't a guarantee.

Comment: "heap optimizations are allowed" well I think maybe I need to ask a new question on "why is GCC not that smart".

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I'm not saying this is a good thing, I'm just stating how it is, I myself dealt with this in the past. Also I provided a workaround that gives mostly the same semantics as what you want. I guess, if this functionality is so important, someone could make a proposal about it for a future standard.

Comment: I'd be glad to see your solution if possible. Did you use a custom type or made some allocator-based vector's specialization?

Comment: @ThePirate42: There are actually a few cases where accessing an array of one type through a pointer to another is permitted.  In particular, from any type, including arrays of any type, to `unsigned char[]` or `std::byte[]`.  And between signed and unsigned variants of the same type, or adjustments to *cv-qualifications*.  These don't cover OP's use cases.  Very importantly, upcasts and pointer-to-initial-member do not qualify -- they have pointer-interconvertibility only for single elements and not for arrays.

Comment: And the permissions do not permit type-punning of wrapper types, such as `std::vector<T>`, `std::range<T>`, `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.  These are completely different types with no cast possible, even when the wrapped types could be cast.  You can create a new `std::range<S>` wrapper for the contents of a `std::range<T>` (if strict-aliasing is obeyed), but you cannot cast a `std::range<T>` to `std::range<S>`.